# Illustrator: how to export the same artwork for two different page sizes (for example, A4 and A3)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, pdf, print-production, artboard

I have a poster design that needs to be printed in two different formats.

The artboard is set to A4, and when I export a PDF, it's exported as A4.

How can I easily export an A3 PDF version of the same poster?

Comment: Turn it 90 degrees, change the artboard to A3, resize the art and save. But it's easier to just save as A3 and resize with "fit to page" when printing on A4

Comment: Thanks! Although it won't work in this case, since I won't print it myself, but send it to a printing company. They are notorious for wanting perfectly prepared PDFs, if I send them A3 and tell them to print in A4 they won't like it

Comment: Yeah, sending two files are also a safe switch on your side as you can see what you want to print and avoid any mismatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in A4 to A3 export option, if that's what you needed.

You should duplicate the existing A4 artboard and manually resize to A3 as a separate artboard.

Comment: Thanks! I did that. Although it's weird that there's no option to do it automatically. Is it really such a rare use case to print the same design in different sizes?

Comment: Not particularly rare, but this is tricky to automate: ok, A4 to A3 is the most basic because it is a 2X upscale, this could be automated. But in most cases things are not proportional, so what if you have a 20x20cm flyer and a 50x80cm poster and a web banner in pixels? No plugin can guess how to handle random sizes, so adjustments need to be made by hand in most cases. Proportional upscale like you needed is just, well, the 'easy' exception.